# JMX for Cloud Applications

Tags: java, configuration, amazon-ec2, cloud, jmx

Is there a solution for managing a *cluster* of dynamically-provisioned servers via JMX?

JMX seems to work fine when working with a known set of servers - type in the hostname to connect to, connect, change settings and look at metrics, and everyone's happy.

What happens when you've got a whole cluster of application instances, and you want to change one setting on all instances in that cluster? Is there any solution that will allow you to change all instances at once, perhaps via some kind of service registry?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [OpenDMK](http://opendmk.java.net/). This is the open sourced version of the [Java Dynamic Management Kit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/index.html). It provides JMX with a [Discovery Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/6mdjrf880/index.html). To quote from the docs:

> The discovery service enables you to discover Java dynamic management
>   agents in a network. This service relies on a discovery client object
>   that sends out multicast requests to find agents. In order to be
>   discovered, an agent must have a registered discovery responder in its
>   MBean server. Applications can also use a discovery monitor that
>   detects when discovery responders are started or stopped.

As for effecting changes on all servers at once, if you implement the discovery service (or something like it), you would be able to quickly compile a list of [JMXServiceURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html)s which in turn could be used to generate a list of [JMXConnector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnector.html)s and thereby a list of connected [MBeanServerConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html)s. From there, it should be simple enough to create a multiplexing wrapper around that list that delegates operations against the wrapper out to each remote JMX instance. (Error handling and timeouts might be a little trickier....)

You might even consider coding up a [MBeanServerInterceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/6mdjrf85d/index.html) which creates a virtual MBeanServer which *looks* like a MBeanServer but is actually the aforementioned multiplexer in disguise.

//Nicholas

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at OpenDMK. Sadly AWS EC2 is my target environment, and it doesn't allow multicast.

Comment: Actually, it's not a very complicated bit of code. You could adapt it to use the Amazon messaging service. Could you post back when you get something working?